# Java 1.8: partial traverse of NavigableMap with amortized O(1) to find following entry?

Tags: java, treemap

I am content to have a O(log n) first operation to find my start point in a

```
NavigableMap<Double,MyThing> navlevel = new TreeMap<>();
```

But in hand-written C++ (or I suppose hand-written Java) once I found a node pointing to the MyThing in question, I could then do a "next" operation on that node which would amortize to just a couple pointer operations.   (If there's a right link, go right then all the way left; otherwise go to your parent until find a node where you're coming from the parent's left child node.)

```
    Map.Entry<Double,MyThing> entry =
        navthing.ceilingEntry( dSomeValue );

    while ( entry != null ) {

        MyThing level = entry.getValue();

        // Process and break on some condition.

        // vvvvvvvvv This I'm sure is O( log n ) and I want it to be faster!
        entry = navthing.higherEntry( entry.getKey() );
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Get `SortedMap` with `tailMap` method or similar, as per your needs, and iterate `SortedMap` entry set like this:

```
NavigableMap<String, String> original = new TreeMap();
original.put("1", "A");
original.put("2", "B");
original.put("3", "C");

//this headmap1 will contain "2" and "3"
SortedMap<String, String> submap1 = original.tailMap("2");
for(Map.Entry<String, String> entry : submap1.entrySet()) {
  String key = entry.getKey();
  String value = entry.getValue();

  System.out.println(key + " => " + value);
}
```

Comment: doesn't entrySet() compose a full set of entries from that point though?  I probably only want the first couple.

Comment: No it doesn't.  The object returned by `entrySet()` is a view of the underlying map.